# insert new values without overwriting previous values sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table i need to add info to for 450 rows, i can identify each row with a unique order number and only need to update 4 of the rows on the table for each order number.

```
update ordercontacts
set firstname = 'joe', lastname = 'smith', email = 'joesmith@smith.com', contacttypeid = 13
where orderid = 1284480
```

this just replaced my values so i had to fix that

i tried this as well

```
insert into ordercontacts
(firstname, lastname, email, contacttypeid)
values
('joe', 'smith', 'jowsmith@smith.com', 13)
where orderid in (1284480)
```

but the syntax is not correct and im not sure what the correct syntax would be

I had thought something like this would work but it doesnt obviously.  Can anyone help me out? Each of the order numbers already has a different contact attached to it, i basically want the end result to be like this:

```
order     firstname   lastname        email               contacttypeid
1284480   joe        smith      joesmith@smith.com         13
1284480   steve      andrews      steve@steve.com         11
```

Im looking to add a new contact on top of one that already exists for each order number.  The syntax for the update i have is only replacing the info that is already there.

Comment: What doesn't work? You've written an update statement, which looks fine. It's not clear what you *expected* it to do, and how what it actual does differs from your expectations. You also claim to have a unique order number to identify records, but your example shows a duplicate order number.

Comment: sorry im in a rush and not explaining fully, there is already a contact in this table, when i run this code it overwrites that contact, i dont want to overwrite, just add a new contact on top of the first one

Comment: update changes the values of existing rows. Try inserting?

Comment: Your order numbers don't appear to be unique.  You say you only want to update 4 rows, but you show two rows and only one of them has been updated. Why is that?

Comment: Well, don't be in a rush. If you can't take the time to post a clear question, how do you expect to get a good answer? The update statement cannot be responsible for the example rows you've posted. It would necessarily have updated both of those rows so that they contained the same data, since they contain the same order number.

Comment: insert into table_name (order, firstname, lastname, email, contacttypeid) values (1284480, 'joe'...);

Comment: im updating it now, thanks for the downvote, deserved that

Comment: I'll add it to an answer then I suppose

Comment: total brainfart on my part, sorry for those whose time i wasted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into table_name (order, firstname, lastname, email, contacttypeid) 
values (1284480, 'joe'...);
```

You're wanting to insert values rather than update. Update will overwrite the values of the existing one, essentially it's "replace x in the row where id = y". Insert will actually create a new row.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking to add a new contact on top of one that already exists for each order number.

Update statements cannot insert new rows. You cannot "add a new contact" via the update statement you've posted.

You need an `insert` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into ordercontacts
(orderid, firstname, lastname, email, contacttypeid)
values
(1284480,'joe', 'smith', 'jowsmith@smith.com', 13)
```